# Can I use "unless otherwise noted this project is released under XXX"?

Tags: linked-libraries, public-domain

I have a project which uses unmodified libraries with MIT-like licenses. I don't include source code of these libraries in my project tree, just include some its configuration files which have full text of its license in the header comment.

I want to release all parts of my project, not directly derived from this libraries, to public domain (e.g. with Unlicense).

Can I just use note like *"unless otherwise noted this project is released under Unlicense"* in LICENSE or README file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write whatever you want, as long as you respect the licences of any external pieces you include/use.

On the other hand, you want any user of your code to be able to find out easily, and without any ambiguities, what is going on. It isn't that much of a hassle to add a `README` file (or a section thereof) spelling out what license(s) apply to which parts of the code, perhaps giving relevant URLs or including relevant licenses verbatim in separate files (perhaps in a `LICENSES`directory?). If you write it out or not, the work to clarify the status of each piece (just to make sure *you* don't commit any transgressions by using foreign code) has to be done anyway.